# I can not figure out how to pull the hours input into my gross pay calculation method

Tags: c#

I was given a homework problem to write some code and then the unit tests to ensure a basic pay calculator functions correctly.  Most of the code was given I just needed to complete the methods for getting the gross pay, getting the taxes and getting the net pay.  When I run the program however my gross pay, taxes, and net pay all come out to be zero.  I think there is something wrong with my gross pay method.

I will put the code I am trying below

```cs
class Program
{
    /* The Main() is not tested and is separate from the 
     * unit tests. Technically, Main() is not needed for 
     * unit tests. */
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int WeeksInPayPeriod = 4;
        List<decimal> hours = new List<decimal>();
        decimal hourlyRate;

        // Prompt and read hourly rate of pay (same for all weeks)
        Console.Write("Hourly Rate: ");
        hourlyRate = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        // Loop to prompt for and read hours for each week
        for (int i = 0; i < WeeksInPayPeriod; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter hours for week {0}: ", i + 1);
            decimal h = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            hours.Add(h);
        }

        // Create Pay object using parameterized constructor
        PayCalculator totalPay = new PayCalculator(hours, hourlyRate);
        // WriteLine() causes object's ToString() to be called
        Console.WriteLine(totalPay);
    }
}

public class PayCalculator
{
    // list holds hours by week in pay period
    private List<decimal> hours;
    // hourly rate is the same for whole pay period
    private decimal hourlyRate;
    private decimal grossPay = 0;
    private decimal tax = 0;
    private decimal netPay = 0;
    decimal reg_time = 40.00M;
    decimal ot = 1.5M;

    // Parameterized constructor. 
    public PayCalculator(List<decimal> hours, decimal hourlyRate)
    {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
    }

    /* Calculates the gross pay for pay period with overtime 
     * paid at time and half for hours over 40 in a week. */
    public decimal GetGrossPay()
    {
        decimal grossPay = 0;
        foreach (decimal h in hours)
        {
            if (hours[0] <= reg_time)
            {
                grossPay += hours[0] * hourlyRate;
            }
            else
            {
                grossPay += (reg_time * hourlyRate) + ((hours[0] - reg_time) * ot);
            }
        }
        /*========================================
         * Complete code to calculate gross pay
         *========================================*/
        return grossPay;
    }

    /* Calculate tax: 15% on first $600.00, 20% on 
       any amount over $600.00 */
    public decimal GetTax()
    {
        decimal tax = 0;
        decimal surplus = 600M;

        if (grossPay <= surplus)
        {
            tax = grossPay * .15M;
        }
        else
        {
            tax = (surplus * .15M) + ((grossPay - surplus) * .2M);
        }

        /*========================================
         * Complete code to calculate gross tax
         *========================================*/
        return tax;
    }

    public decimal GetNetPay()
    {
        decimal netPay = 0;

        netPay = grossPay - tax;
        /*========================================
         * Complete code to calculate net pay
         *========================================*/
        return netPay;
    }

    /*
     * ToString() returns pay info in string formatted like:
     * Gross pay: 830.00, Tax: 136.00, Net pay: 694.00
     */
    override
    public string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Gross pay: {0:F2}, Tax: {1:F2}, Net pay: {2:F2}",
            this.grossPay, this.tax, this.netPay);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to step through this code with a debugger, inspecting each variable as they change so you can ask a question about the specific part that is breaking. Alternatively, write good unit tests against `PayCalcualator` (and then debug those!)

Comment: _" I think there is something wrong with my gross pay method"_ set a breakpoint at the beginning of the method, then step through it line-by-line.

Comment: **[Navigating through Code using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

The methods are not changing PayCalculator's attributes (they're just returning values to nothing).

Assuming the end goal here is to make the ToString() display something else than zeroes, you should make your methods assign values to attributes. For example, with GetGrossPay():

```
    /* Calculates the gross pay for pay period with overtime 
     * paid at time and half for hours over 40 in a week. */
    public decimal GetGrossPay()
    {
        decimal grossPay = 0;
        foreach (decimal h in hours)
        {
            if (hours[0] <= reg_time)
            {
                grossPay += hours[0] * hourlyRate;
            }
            else
            {
                grossPay += (reg_time * hourlyRate) + ((hours[0] - reg_time) * ot);
            }
        }
        /*========================================
         * Complete code to calculate gross pay
         *========================================*/
        this.grossPay = grossPay;
        return grossPay;
    }
```

Note the added line

```
this.grossPay = grossPay;
```

If you don't need the value returned you could change the method return type to void and get rid of the return line too.